# jquery get value of select box after ajax load return null

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

i have select box

```
<select id="operator">
</select>
```

then iam use jquery to load selected option

```
<script>
   $("#operator").load("select.php");
</script>
```

after that i use

```
$("#operator").val();
```

but return null

i try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var operator = $('#operator').val();
alert(operator);
```

});

still retun null

and try again

```
$(document).on('ready','#operator', function(){
   var operator = $('#operator').val();
alert(operator);
```

});

still return null

how to get value after ajax load?

complete code

```
<Select id="operator">
</select>

<Script>
$("#operator").load('select.php');

$(function(){
  var operator =   $("#operator").val();
  alert(operator);
}
</script>
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because the AJAX request hasn't completed yet, which means the `select` does not have any `option`s yet.

So try this:

```
$("#operator").load("select.php", function() {
    var value = $( '#operator' ).val();
    alert( value );
});
```

Or if that doesn't work, then try with this one:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    $("#operator").load("select.php", function() {
        var value = $( '#operator' ).val();
        alert( value );
    });
} );
```

If that still doesn't work, then you should share the content/code in *select.php*, which I assumed generates (or should generate) some `option`s.

Comment: thanks you ms sally, you saved my day, sorry for long time to accept an answer